# How to sort rows in SQL that contain both numeric and alphanumeric values in ascending order?

Tags: sql, sorting, alphanumeric

I have the following rows returned from my SQL query- can someone please help with a generic sorting code to sort the values in ascending order?

```
('High_Speed'),
('M1 Speed'),
('M13 Speed'),
('M14 Speed'),
('M2 Speed'),
('M3 Speed'),
('Medium_Speed'),
('Test1 zone1 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone11 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone2 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone21 High_Speed'),
('Medium_Speed'),
('Zone206 Speed')
```

expected sorting-

```
('High_Speed'),
('M1 Speed'),
('M2 Speed'),
('M3 Speed'),
('M13 Speed'),
('M14 Speed'),
('Medium_Speed'),
('Test1 zone1 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone2 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone11 High_Speed'),
('Test1 zone21 High_Speed'),
('Medium_Speed'),
('Zone206 Speed')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Not really a good way.. even in a generic programming language this problem is hard to categorize (strings are opaque values without general content-knowledge). Ideally there is additional information that might be used.

Comment: Another approach might be to translate all nnnn, nnn, nn, n into nnnn, 0nnn, 00nn, 000n for the values used to order (the transform would still be a string).

Answer (score 0):

The most generic method is to use a `case` expression:

```
order by (case col
            when 'High_Speed' then 1
            when 'M1 Speed' then 2
            when 'M2 Speed' then 3
            when 'M3 Speed' then 4
            when 'M13 Speed' then 5
            when 'M14 Speed' then 6
            when 'Medium_Speed' then 7
            when 'Test1 zone1 High_Speed' then 8
            when 'Test1 zone2 High_Speed' then 9
            when 'Test1 zone11 High_Speed' then 10
            when 'Test1 zone21 High_Speed' then 11
            when 'Medium_Speed' then 12
            when 'Zone206 Speed' then 13
            else 999
          end)
```

Comment: Not really any point even writing a query if this is a presented solution as it only works with the specific data.. (or, one might just as well write a table with an explicit ordering column).

Comment: @user2864740 . . . This answers the question that the OP asked.  If you have a different question, ask it as a NEW question.

Comment: this seems to be hard coding- reason being my rows will be dynamically returned and will not always contain the same string as posted in my question above. Any better approach/solution code to address this issue?

Comment: @Rajeev . . . Then you should ask a *new* question and be much clearer on the rules that you are using for ordering.  This answers the question that you asked here.

Comment: If the question is so ill-written or lacking in details (hmm, no close votes for focus or comments asking for relevant details?), *consider not writing an “answer” simply to pad votes..*

Comment: @user2864740 . . . Despite your opinions, the question is well written.  This correctly answers the question.  It happens not to do what the OP really wants, because -- although clear -- the question is not what the OP really wants.

Comment: “Then you should ask a new question and be much clearer on the rules ..” - flip flop. Still not a good ‘answer’, *especially as it ignores the first sentence of the (updated?) question.*

Comment: It’s also misleading and simply rude to claim others are presenting an “opinion” while presenting your own “opinion” as facts - call it both ways, however it is.

Comment: **If** the OP asked “How can I sort this fixed set of rows..” - however, that  is not the case, and has never been anything except an assumption as to the data used. My “opinion” then is to use the example data as examples while your “opinion” has to take it as the only set of values *without any additional basis*.